# Wordpress White screen of death after migration

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

So after i moved my website from a local WAMP installation to a hosting provider, I am getting a white screen of death. The website is working normally, except that i cannot access wp-admin. I have tried disabling the theme and the plugins(it's now on twentyfifteen) but the error still persists. Before i disabled those, debug would show something like 'WP:Widget is deprecated, please use __construct()' so i searched online and i figured it should be one of the plugins or the theme, but that doesn't do the trick either. Now, debug shows nothing and the white screen persists. Maybe it's related to the php version of the new hosting? I have tried reaching out to them, but until they answer maybe someobody here knows what I should do. Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: I have suggestion for you please change a favicon it still display WAMP sever Icon.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Case 1 : You can Access Admin**

- Remove htaccess from root
- Login into admin update paramlinks
- deactive and active theme you are using.

**Case 2 : You can't Access Admin (Try With FTP)**

- **Disable Plugins**

  your plugins by simply renaming the `plugins` directory to `plugins.old`
- **Disable Theme**

if you rename your active theme the same way we renamed plugins, WordPress will automatically fall back to using a default WordPress theme.

- **Enable Debugger**

  WP_DEBUG, it’s a constant that you can add to your wp-config.php file on your website, that will output any specific errors that are occurring on the site the same way the Windows blue screen does.

That's it.

Comment: Thank you for answering but i have already tried all those things.. i specified in my question

Comment: Did you try from FTP?

Comment: I used the cpanel file manager. Renamed plugins and disabled them manually from phpmyadmin. Theme is now default too.

Comment: http://restaurantelena.ro . It.s now the twentyfifteen theme with no plugins but the wp-admin is not working

Comment: wait i see it works with wp-login not wp-admin.. it didn.t cross my mind to try that. Thank you very much confirmed it works now :)

Comment: what is an issue?

Answer (score 0):

In my case the error was because file permissions. In localhost all the files was owned by `www-data:www-data` but in production the right user is root so I just need to change all files to root with:

```
sudo chown root:root -R /var/www
```

And that fixes everything